# Using LinqToTwitter in Console App and getting AggregateException Error

Tags: linq-to-twitter

I'm trying to do a basic SingleUserAuthorizer call to twitter. I am getting this Exception when I try the User Linq request. Any ideas?

> Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll

```
var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
{
    CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
    {
        ConsumerKey = twitterConsumerKey,
        ConsumerSecret = twitterConsumerSecret,
        OAuthToken = twitterAccessTokenSecret,
        AccessToken = twitterAccessToken
    }
};
//await auth.AuthorizeAsync();
var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

User user = 
    (from tweet in twitterCtx.User
    where tweet.Type == UserType.Show &&
    tweet.ScreenName == member.screenName
    select tweet)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

We resolved the issue via this discussion on GitHub:

https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/issues/45